i can't download my bundle (aab) from google play console from internal test
I am new to both stack overflow and play console, can someone explain why I can't download my AAB published as an internal test on the play console? I invited my Google account from the mailing list (which by the way doesn't even work since I had to copy the link manually). I accepted the invitation with the account concerned and when I go to the test release page, I get an app with an empty image, the name with the one in the gradle file (so it's something like com.yourdomain.myapp (unreviewed). I also signed the bundle as per the flutter procedure, in fact, Play Console does not give me errors Besides not letting me download the app, it says my device is not compatible (it's a Redmi Note 9s and doesn't have Android under 4.4). I also have developer mode enabled on the account. It also tells me: that this item is not available. Help I don't know how to do it.
The error

I tried rebuilding the bundle, and logging in with other accounts but nothing.
